# Conditional Sum with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Using sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1' : ['a','a','b','b','a'],
               'key2' : ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'],
               'data1' : np.random.randn(5),
               'data2' : np. random.randn(5)})
```

df

```
    data1        data2     key1  key2
0    0.361601    0.375297    a   one
1    0.069889    0.809772    a   two
2    1.468194    0.272929    b   one
3   -1.138458    0.865060    b   two
4   -0.268210    1.250340    a   one
```

I'm trying to figure out how to group the data by key1 and sum only the data1 values where key2 equals 'one'.

Here's what I've tried

```
def f(d,a,b):
    d.ix[d[a] == b, 'data1'].sum()

df.groupby(['key1']).apply(f, a = 'key2', b = 'one').reset_index()
```

But this gives me a dataframe with 'None' values

```
index   key1    0
0       a       None
1       b       None
```

Any ideas here?  I'm looking for the Pandas equivalent of the following SQL:

```
SELECT Key1, SUM(CASE WHEN Key2 = 'one' then data1 else 0 end)
FROM df
GROUP BY key1
```

FYI - I've seen [conditional sums for pandas aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259547/conditional-sums-for-pandas-aggregate)  but couldn't transform the answer provided there to work with sums rather than counts.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First groupby the key1 column:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('key1')
```

and then for each group take the subDataFrame where key2 equals 'one' and sum the data1 column:

```
In [12]: g.apply(lambda x: x[x['key2'] == 'one']['data1'].sum())
Out[12]:
key1
a       0.093391
b       1.468194
dtype: float64
```

To explain what's going on let's look at the 'a' group:

```
In [21]: a = g.get_group('a')

In [22]: a
Out[22]:
      data1     data2 key1 key2
0  0.361601  0.375297    a  one
1  0.069889  0.809772    a  two
4 -0.268210  1.250340    a  one

In [23]: a[a['key2'] == 'one']
Out[23]:
      data1     data2 key1 key2
0  0.361601  0.375297    a  one
4 -0.268210  1.250340    a  one

In [24]: a[a['key2'] == 'one']['data1']
Out[24]:
0    0.361601
4   -0.268210
Name: data1, dtype: float64

In [25]: a[a['key2'] == 'one']['data1'].sum()
Out[25]: 0.093391000000000002
```

It may be slightly easier/clearer to do this by restricting the dataframe to just those with key2 equals one first:

```
In [31]: df1 = df[df['key2'] == 'one']

In [32]: df1
Out[32]:
      data1     data2 key1 key2
0  0.361601  0.375297    a  one
2  1.468194  0.272929    b  one
4 -0.268210  1.250340    a  one

In [33]: df1.groupby('key1')['data1'].sum()
Out[33]:
key1
a       0.093391
b       1.468194
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Awesome!  I'm trying this out on my actual data (might take awhile) but I think this is what I was looking for.  Thanks so much

Comment: Just searched the documentation and a quick google search...couldn't precisely find what you're referring to by groupby filter...could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @AllenQ It's a new method in dev (will be in 0.11.1 when it comes out soon).

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using apply in these scenarios

Comment: This is honestly one of the best responses ever on SO. Breaking it down and showing how it works took me from groupby novice to pro. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 24):

I think that today with pandas 0.23 you can do this:

```
import numpy as np

 df.assign(result = np.where(df['key2']=='one',df.data1,0))\
   .groupby('key1').agg({'result':sum})
```

The advantage of this is that you can apply it to more than one column of the same dataframe

```
df.assign(
 result1 = np.where(df['key2']=='one',df.data1,0),
 result2 = np.where(df['key2']=='two',df.data1,0)
  ).groupby('key1').agg({'result1':sum, 'result2':sum})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your dataframe *before* you perform your `groupby` operation. If this reduces your series index due to all values being out-of-scope, you can use `reindex` with `fillna`:

```
res = df.loc[df['key2'].eq('one')]\
        .groupby('key1')['data1'].sum()\
        .reindex(df['key1'].unique()).fillna(0)

print(res)

key1
a    3.631610
b    0.978738
c    0.000000
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

#### Setup

I have added an additional row for demonstration purposes.

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['a','a','b','b','a','c'],
                   'key2': ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
                   'data1': np.random.randn(6),
                   'data2': np.random.randn(6)})
```