# Conditional Sums based on another DataFrame column value

Tags: python, pandas, sum, conditional-statements, dataframe

I'm trying to sum all the `value` where `date1` matches `date2` for each row in my dataframe, which is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sums).

```
id        value       date1       date2   sum
A         150      4/8/2014    3/8/2014   nan
B         100      5/8/2014    2/8/2014   nan
B         200      7/8/2014    5/8/2014   100
A         200      4/8/2014    3/8/2014   nan
A         300      6/8/2014    4/8/2014   350
```

I've tried the following but keep getting *'Lengths must match to compare'* error.

```
grp = df.groupby('id')
df['sum'] = grp.apply(lambda x: x[x['date1'] == df['date2'].values]['value'].sum())
```

Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Problem is with: `x['date1'] == df['date2']`, Series have different lengths.

Comment: IIUC doesn't the following give you what you want: `df1 = df.set_index('id')
df1.loc[df1['date1'].isin(df1['date2']),'value'].sum(level=0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) where use another [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `0` to `NaN`:

```
print df

#  id  value      date1      date2  sum
#0  A    150 2014-04-08 2014-03-08  NaN
#1  B    100 2014-05-08 2014-02-08  NaN
#2  B    200 2014-07-08 2014-05-08  100
#3  A    200 2014-04-08 2014-03-08  NaN
#4  A    300 2014-06-08 2014-04-08  350


def f(x):
    x['sum1'] = x.date2.apply(lambda y:  x[x.date1 == y].value.sum()).replace(0, np.nan)
    return x

df = df.groupby('id').apply(f)

print df

#  id  value      date1      date2  sum  sum1
#0  A    150 2014-04-08 2014-03-08  NaN   NaN
#1  B    100 2014-05-08 2014-02-08  NaN   NaN
#2  B    200 2014-07-08 2014-05-08  100   100
#3  A    200 2014-04-08 2014-03-08  NaN   NaN
#4  A    300 2014-06-08 2014-04-08  350   350
```

Comment: thanks, but actually I'm trying to achieve the `sum` column in my example. sorry if that isn't clear.

Comment: thanks, but this ignores the `id`, hence not exactly what I need. but thanks for the prompt responses!

Comment: it works! thanks jezrael, appreciate your helpfulness!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this apply function:

```
def checkSum(record):
    date2 = record
    sum = df[df["date1"] == date2]["value"].sum()
    if sum == 0:
        return float('nan')
    else:
        return sum

df['sum2'] = df["date2"].apply(checkSum)
```

Comment: thanks, but this ignores the `id` field too. I tried `df['sum2'] = grp["date2"].apply(checkSum)` but got the _Series lengths must match to compare_ error.