# python pandas conditional sum on dataframe which is grouped on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To illustrate my problem I have an example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                    'key2': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 
                    'key3': [10, 5, 15, 10, 5, 10, 20, 10, 20, 5],  
                    'zdata': [2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6]})
```

which when

```
df1 = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
df1 = df1.agg({'zdata' : [np.mean]})
```

produces

```
                zdata
                mean
key1 key2 key3      
0    a    10       2
     b    5        4 * (new group1)
          15       2 * (new group1)
     c    10       4
1    a    5        3 * (new group2)
          10       5 * (new group2)
          20       6 * (new group2)
     b    10       5
          20       5
     c    5        6
```

I now need to find the mean of zdata and key3 by grouping key1 and key2 only where key3 has a '5' and any additional number ( ie. the rows marked with an * in the above table)

So the desired result would be

```
                zdata
                mean
key1 key2 key3      
0    b    10       3
1    a    11.6     4.6
```

I am certain a lambda function will get there like this example [[Python Pandas Conditional Sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sums][1]) but this problem is grouped on multiple columns

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think better is use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) as `agg`, because result is `DataFrame` with no `Multiindex` in columns. Then you can use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) and `len` and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) again:

```
#instaed of agg use:
df1 = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], as_index=False)['zdata'].mean()
print df1
   key1 key2  key3  zdata
0     0    a    10      2
1     0    b     5      4
2     0    b    15      2
3     0    c    10      4
4     1    a     5      3
5     1    a    10      5
6     1    a    20      6
7     1    b    10      5
8     1    b    20      5
9     1    c     5      6

#filter rows by conditions
df2 = df1.groupby(['key1', 'key2']).filter(lambda x: (x.key3 == 5).any() & (len(x) > 1))
print df2
   key1 key2  key3  zdata
1     0    b     5      4
2     0    b    15      2
4     1    a     5      3
5     1    a    10      5
6     1    a    20      6

print df2.groupby(['key1', 'key2'], as_index=False).mean()
   key1 key2       key3     zdata
0     0    b  10.000000  3.000000
1     1    a  11.666667  4.666667
```