# Python: group by sum with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition' : ['a','b','b','b','a','a'],
               'name' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three'],
               'data1' : [7, 3, 48, 13, 27, 12]})
df
  condtion  data1   name
0   a          7    one
1   b          3    one
2   b         48    two
3   b         13    three
4   a         27    three
5   a         12    three
```

For each name I want to sum on `data1` and use information of `condition=a` if I have that information, `condition=b` otherwise. At the end I would like a dataframe like the following:

```
df1 
    name   total
0   one      7
1   two     48
2   three   39
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `sum` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last replace NaNs for missing catagories `a` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['name','condition'], sort=False)['data1'].sum().unstack()
df['total'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'])
print (df)
condition     a     b  total
name                        
one         7.0   3.0    7.0
two         NaN  48.0   48.0
three      39.0  13.0   39.0
```

And for new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)[['name','total']]
print (df1)
    name  total
0    one    7.0
1    two   48.0
2  three   39.0
```

Another solution with `apply`:

```
def f(x):
    if (x['condition'] == 'a').any():
        return x.loc[x['condition'] == 'a', 'data1'].sum() 
    else:
        return x.loc[x['condition'] == 'b', 'data1'].sum()

df1 = df.groupby('name', sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(name='total')
print (df1)
    name  total
0    one      7
1    two     48
2  three     39
```

---

Better one is create Series for aggregating filtered DataFrame and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), but this solution omit all `name`s groups with no `a` or `b` conditions:

```
a = df.loc[df['condition'] == 'a'].groupby('name', sort=False)['data1'].sum()
b = df.loc[df['condition'] == 'b'].groupby('name', sort=False)['data1'].sum()

df = a.combine_first(b).reset_index(name='total')
print (df)
    name  total
0    one    7.0
1  three   39.0
2    two   48.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `name` and `condition` to find the `sum` of `data1` and then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `name` and `condition` before selecting first entry for each group in grouping by `name`:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'condition'])['data1'].sum().reset_index(name='total').sort_values(['name','condition']).groupby(['name']).first().reset_index()[['name', 'total']]
```

Output:

```
    name    total
0   one     7
1   three   39
2   two     48
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='sum'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition' : ['a','b','b','b','a','a'],
                   'name' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three'],
                   'data1' : [7, 3, 48, 13, 27, 12]})

res = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='condition', values='data1', aggfunc='sum')

condition     a     b
name                 
one         7.0   3.0
three      39.0  13.0
two         NaN  48.0
```

Then apply [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and clean up:

```
res = res.assign(total=res['a'].fillna(res['b']).astype(int))\
         .reset_index().rename_axis('', 1)\
         .loc[:, ['name', 'total']]

print(res)

    name  total
0    one      7
1  three     39
2    two     48
```