# How to do conditional aggregation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a conditional aggregation with pandas but with two conditionals, I have seen this [Python Pandas Conditional Sum with Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sum-with-groupby) and I have found really useful but if I added another condition for example:

`g.apply(lambda x: x[x[x['key2'] == 'one']['data2']<0.4]['data1'].sum())`
i.e add a condition that I want to sum the ones which Key2 is equal to one and that data2 is less than 0.4. But this doesnt work.

This is the error that I got:
Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: can you provide a sample dataframe on which this is supposed to operate, along with the desired output?

Comment: maybe `lambda x: x[(x['key2'] == 'one') & (x['data2'] < 0.4)]['data1'].sum()` ?

Answer (score 1):

if number of rows of `x` is N1, number of rows of `x[x['key2'] == 'one']` will be N2 <= N1 and also number of rows of `x[x['key2'] == 'one']['data2']<0.4` will be N2 too. Now, in the final `x[...]` stage, `x` has N1 rows and the mask inside `[...]` (which is `x[x['key2'] == 'one']['data2']<0.4`) has N2 rows. And you cannot slice a dataframe with a boolean mask of different length. So you can use @pmarcol's suggestion:

```
g.apply(lambda x: x[(x['key2'] == 'one') & (x['data2'] < 0.4)]['data1'].sum())
```