# pandas: groupby with multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Would you, please help me, to group pandas dataframe by multiple conditions.

Here is how I do it in SQL:

```
with a as (
  select high 
,sum( case when qr = 1 and now = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) q1_bad
,sum( case when qr = 2 and now = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) q2_bad
  from #tmp2
  group by high
)
select a.high from a
where q1_bad >= 2 and q2_bad >= 2 and a.high is not null
```

Here is the part of the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame()

a['client'] = range(35)
a['high'] = ['02','47','47','47','79','01','43','56','46','47','17','58','42','90','47','86','41','56',
'55','49','47','49','95','23','46','47','80','80','41','49','46','49','56','46','31']
a['qr'] = ['1','1','1','1','2','1','1','2','2','1','1','2','2',
'2','1','1','1','2','1','2','1','2','2','1','1','1','2','2','1','1',
'1','1','1','1','2']
a['now'] = ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0',
'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0']
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: did a little googling for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sum-with-groupby

Comment: jeffery_the_wind, thank you very much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very similar, you need to define your columns ahead of the groupby then apply your operation.

assuming you have actual integers and not strings.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a.assign(q1_bad = np.where((a['qr'].eq(1) & a['now'].eq(1)),1,0),
         q2_bad = np.where((a['qr'].eq(2) & a['now'].eq(1)),1,0)

).groupby('high')[['q1_bad','q2_bad']].sum()
```

---

```
     q1_bad  q2_bad
high                
01         0       0
02         0       0
17         0       0
23         0       0
31         0       0
41         0       0
42         0       1
43         0       0
46         0       0
47         0       0
49         1       0
55         0       0
56         0       0
58         0       0
79         0       0
80         0       0
86         0       0
90         0       0
95         0       0
```

for you extra where clause you can filter it one of many ways, but for ease we can add `query` at the end.

```
a.dropna(subset='high').assign(q1_bad = np.where((a['qr'].eq(1) & a['now'].eq(1)),1,0),
         q2_bad = np.where((a['qr'].eq(2) & a['now'].eq(1)),1,0)

).groupby('high')[['q1_bad','q2_bad']].sum().query('q2_bad >= 2 and q1_bad >= 2')
```

Comment: Manakin, thanks a lot. Your code works perfectly. The only thing I corrected is q2_bad on q1_bad in the final  query.