# Pandas conditional sum with groupby not working

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I tried the suggestion from here:
[Python Pandas Conditional Sum with Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266129/python-pandas-conditional-sum-with-groupby)

Not sure what/where I did wrong. Can someone point out and help? Please....

Tried this:

```
df.groupby('c').aggregate(lambda x: x['a'][(x['a'] > 1) & (x['b'] == 1)].mean())
```

Replacing with my column headers and conditions, and changing to sum:

```
df1.groupby('Store').aggregate(lambda x: x['Units'][(x['Units'] > 0) & (x['Status'] == 'ACKD')].sum())
```

Got a list of errors, too long to post here. Guess the main one is:

```
KeyError: 'Units'
```

df1:

```
Store Units Sent Recd Status SentMth RecdMth RptMth Days

201 2 2021-03-15 2021-03-15 INTR 3 3 3 0

201 1 2021-03-15 2021-03-15 INTR 3 3 3 0
```

this one is working fine:

```
df1.groupby('Store')['Units'].aggregate(lambda x: x[x > 0].sum())
```

```
Store

201 7

202 7

Name: Units, Length: 79, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Seems the link you referenced uses `apply` not `aggregate`. Should work with `apply` no?

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker! Spot on! It worked. Your help is much appreciated to a newbie like me.