# Pandas, getting mean and sum with groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame, `df`, which looks like this:

```
index  New  Old  Map      Limit  count
1       93   35   54       > 18      1
2      163   93  116       > 18      1
3      134   78   96       > 18      1
4      117   81   93       > 18      1
5      194  108  136       > 18      1
6      125   57   79      <= 18      1
7       66   39   48       > 18      1
8      120   83   95       > 18      1
9      150   98  115       > 18      1
10     149   99  115       > 18      1
11     148   85  106       > 18      1
12      92   55   67      <= 18      1
13      64   24   37       > 18      1
14      84   53   63       > 18      1
15      99   70   79       > 18      1
```

I need to produce a data frame that looks like this:

```
Limit        <=18             >18
         total  mean     total  mean
New       xx1    yy1      aa1    bb1
Old       xx2    yy2      aa2    bb2
MAP       xx3    yy3      aa3    bb3
```

I tried this without success:

```
df.groupby('Limit')['New', 'Old', 'MAP'].[sum(), mean()].T without success.
```

How can I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use groupby to apply multiple functions to multiple columns in Pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26206415/5276797)

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once): `df.groupby('Limit')['New', 'Old', 'MAP'].agg(['sum', 'mean'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), then transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df[['New', 'Old', 'Map', 'Limit']].groupby('Limit').agg([sum, 'mean']).T.unstack())

Limit  <= 18           > 18            
         sum   mean     sum        mean
New    217.0  108.5  1581.0  121.615385
Old    112.0   56.0   946.0   72.769231
Map    146.0   73.0  1153.0   88.692308
```

I edit by [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341727/pandas-getting-mean-and-sum-with-groupby#comment62200796_37341727), it looks nicer:

```
print (df.groupby('Limit')['New', 'Old', 'Map', 'Limit'].agg([sum, 'mean']).T.unstack())
```

And if need `total` columns:

```
print (df.groupby('Limit')['New', 'Old', 'Map', 'Limit']
         .agg({'total':sum, 'mean': 'mean'})
         .T
         .unstack(0))

Limit  <= 18           > 18            
       total   mean   total        mean
New    217.0  108.5  1581.0  121.615385
Old    112.0   56.0   946.0   72.769231
Map    146.0   73.0  1153.0   88.692308
```