# Pandas: Aggregate differently based on group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

So let's say I have some data as follow:

```
patient_id  lab_type  value
1           food       10
1           food       8
2           food       3
2           food       5
1           shot       4
1           shot       10
2           shot       2
2           shot       4
```

Then I will group things such as `groupby(['patient_id', 'lab_type'])`

After that, I'd like to aggregate on `value` but different for each `lab_type`. On `food` I'd like to aggregate using `mean` and on `shot` I'd like to aggregate using `sum`.

The final data should look like this:

```
  patient_id  lab_type  value
  1           food       9 (10 + 8 / 2)
  2           food       4 (3 + 5 / 2)
  1           shot       14 (10 + 4)
  2           shot       6 (2 + 4)
```

Comment: Just write a function that checks the `lab_type` of its input and does different stuff depending on what it is, then `apply` that function to the groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On food I'd like to aggregate using mean and on shot I'd like to aggregate using sum.

Just use `.apply` and pass a custom function:

```
def calc(g):
    if g.iloc[0].lab_type == 'shot':
        return sum(g.value)
    else:
        return np.mean(g.value)
result = df.groupby(['patient_id', 'lab_type']).apply(calc)
```

Here `calc` receives the per-group dataframe as shown in [Panda's split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply). As a result you get what you want:

```
patient_id  lab_type
1           food         9
            shot        14
2           food         4
            shot         6
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be the most concise, however, can you explain what g refers to in this case and what you need to return?

Comment: `calc` gets called once for every group, `g` refers to the data in the group (in fact, a DataFrame). The returned value is the result of whatever operation you apply, in this case it is the calculated statistic. Essentially, Pandas automatically concatenates all results.

Answer (score 1):

I try modified [john](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981467/2901002) answer:

You can use [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df
   patient_id lab_type  value
0           1     food     10
1           1     food      8
2           2     food      3
3           2     food      5
4           1     shot      4
5           1     shot     10
6           2     shot      2
7           2     shot      4


df1 = df[df.lab_type =="food"].groupby(['patient_id']).mean()
df1['lab_type'] = 'food'
print df1
            value lab_type
patient_id                
1               9     food
2               4     food

df2 = df[df.lab_type =="shot"].groupby(['patient_id']).sum()
df2['lab_type'] = 'shot'
print df2
            value lab_type
patient_id                
1              14     shot
2               6     shot

print pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index()
   patient_id  value lab_type
0           1      9     food
1           2      4     food
2           1     14     shot
3           2      6     shot
```

Comment: This is a solid answer however slightly verbose compared to mira's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259547/conditional-sums-for-pandas-aggregate) looks promising. Starting from this I came up with the following code which should work out for you.

Testdata:

```
data = [{"A" : 1, "B" : "food", "C" : 10},
{"A" : 1, "B" : "food", "C" : 8},
{"A" : 2, "B" : "food", "C" : 3},
{"A" : 2, "B" : "food", "C" : 5},
{"A" : 1, "B" : "shot", "C" : 4},
{"A" : 1, "B" : "shot", "C" : 10},
{"A" : 2, "B" : "shot", "C" : 2},
{"A" : 2, "B" : "shot", "C" : 4}]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Actual code:

```
res = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(
  lambda x: pd.Series(
    {"value" : x.C.mean() if x.iloc[0].B == "food" else x.C.sum()}
  )
)
```

This results in

```
        value
A B          
1 food      9
  shot     14
2 food      4
  shot      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `P` be your DataFrame.

```
P[P.lab_type =="food"].groupby(['patient_id']).aggregate(np.avg)
```

and similarly for the `shot` group and [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) the results.