# How to group by a single column in pandas and expand unique values with agg count?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For anyone stumbling across a similar problem, this answered my question: [conditional sums for pandas aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259547/conditional-sums-for-pandas-aggregate)

I've had success doing a normal groupby on data like this...

```
score |  type     |
--------------------
1     |  type1    |
3     |  type6    |
5     |  type4    |
3     |  type21   |
2     |  type3    |
4     |  type1    |
...etc...
```

ideal output

That resulted in something like this...

```
score |  type     |
--------------------
5     |  882    |
4     |  183    |
3     |  458    |
2     |  1156   |
1     |  10934  |
```

But I want to be able to take the unique values of the "type" column into account and end up with something more like this...

```
score | type1 | type 2 | type 3 ... etc.
------------------------------        
5     |   20  |    4   |   ..  |
4     |    3  |    17  |   ..  |
3     |    1  |    12  |   ..  |
2     |   14  |    9   |   ..  |
1     |   70  |    13  |   ..  |
```

I'm not sure if a groupby is the right approach but I've been banging my head against this and need help.

Comment: use `pandas.crosstab`?

Comment: I don't see how you use crosstab to get the aggregations of the different types grouped by score? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you provide a complete input/output example (without `...`)?